# Ion-footer does not get pushed up when keyboard is visible (ios and android)

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic-keyboard

My issue is that the toolbar remains at the bottom of the page.

This is my footer code:

Blockquote

```
<ion-footer>
    <ion-toolbar>
        <button ion-button clear class="color--blue text__align--center background--light-gray position--relative" (click)="!isAttaching ? triggerFileUpload($event) : false">
            Max 50(Mb)
        </button>
        <div class="background--blue height--4 position--absolute position--bottom--0 position--left--0" [ngClass]="{'display--hidden': !isAttaching}" #loader style="width: 0px"></div>
    </ion-toolbar>
</ion-footer>
```

I have used these settings:

```
<preference name="KeyboardResize" value="true" />
<preference name="KeyboardResizeMode" value="ionic" />
```

And also

```
<preference name="KeyboardResize" value="true" />
<preference name="KeyboardResizeMode" value="native" />
```

Alongside:

```
scrollPadding: true,
scrollAssist: true
```

Plus, for Android I am using:

```
<edit-config file="AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge" target="/manifest/application/activity">
    <activity android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
</edit-config>
```

None of the above did the trick.
Anybody else got another suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

You should add this cordova plugin `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard --save`
And use the first settings you tried, the alongside it’s not necessary

Comment: I am already using    ``<plugin name="cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard" spec="^2.1.3" />``

Comment: Try removing ion footer and adding to the parent position: absolute bottom: 0

Comment: tried that .. but this causes a lot more issues on the long run, because the page I am using the footer is a message page, where I have two inputs and a textarea that will grow .. and using the bottom positioned footer is causing issues. The problem that I am seeing here is also related to my other issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53164493/keyboard-plugin-over-ion-list-elements-does-not-add-padding-to-content-in-ioni .. this is another thing that I could not crack